# Can i send a default value for file uploads.

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5, forms, http-post

Hie, 
I know setting up a default file upload is a security issues but is there a way where I can send a value if user does not select a file?

For instance i have an array of file as below:

`<input type="file" name="image[]">`

As you can see i have an array of image files. So, therefore if user is sending an array of data along with images I need to know the position of each images in accordance with the array of data. For example:

```
array1[0] Image[0]
array2[1] Image[1]
```

I need to send the data as above such that if there are 5 arrays of data I need to know for each array of data a particular image is assigned. Now if user fails to upload an image at position 0 i need to know at what position the user was unable to upload image. At the moment if user could not upload the image at position 0 the data passes would be

```
    array1[0] Image[0]
    array2[1]
```

But I would like the following thing to happen if user fails to upload an image at position 0 (for example)

```
array1[0] "no-image"
array2[1] Image[1]
```

or

```
array1[0] Image[0] = "no image"
array2[1] Image[1]
```

Just want to let the array after form submittion to know at which position the image was failed to upload by the user such that i could assign a default image name at the backend.

Comment: How about checking in php, after submit, if the file is set.. if not, assign the default value, else, use the file.

Comment: You can check If image added or not, if added then save user uploaded image otherwise create default.png etc image and save that in DB.

Comment: Yes it is true I can check if image was uploaded or not. But how does it work for arrays of images. How can I check at which position the image was not uploaded.

Comment: Additionally there is an add button where user can add array of images. So if user adds 5 file input boxes and uploads only three images, then the array shows only three images uploaded. I need to know how many images did the user add in first place.

Comment: You need to create single file upload boxes for each data box, assigning matching names.

Comment: Could you provide me with an example. or a link